# authentication inside a program

Tags: security, authentication

I am developing a program and I would like to ask the users for 
username and password and i would like to program a mechanism for it, what I don't know is where to save the username and password (I don't want to have it hardcoded in the code and not written in a DB)

thanks

Comment: If you want something easy and out of the box, look into asp .net templates in MS Visual Studio. PW are encrypted and "salted"

Comment: i need it for a winform application

Comment: The web app templates are perfect for you then. Microsoft Azure integrates perfectly, of course. You can write your code first (log-in wizards, etc), then connect to an Azure sql server and it takes core of itself. But not storing at all in a DB leave you with few options. The sql server stores only in encrypted pw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want or can't use DB, you can save it into some configuration file.
But remember security - don't store it in plaintext. Use some encryption. Explanation for example here:
http://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/